# Checkboxes in access panel won't stay unticked

Tags: nodes

There's a page on my website that can't be made public because the checkboxes in the access panel - when I try to edit the page - won't stay unticked. I untick the checkboxes and hit save, but when I go back to edit the page again, the checkbox has become ticked again.

Here's a screenshot to highlight where the issue is. Is there a setting I need to turn off or something?

[image: Screenshot of the checkboxes that won't stay unticked]

Thanks to No Sssweat and Beebee for the tips. There are error messages in the log, which are pasted below. Looks like an error from the 'Simple Access' module, which is apparently up-to-date.

Error Message:

> Notice: Undefined index: members in Drupal\simple_access\Element\SimpleAccessGroups::processSimpleAccessGroups() (line 74 of /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/modules/simple_access/src/Element/SimpleAccessGroups.php) #0 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(584): *drupal_error_handler_real(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/lz7m8hr2s...', 74, Array) #1 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/modules/simple_access/src/Element/SimpleAccessGroups.php(74): *drupal_error_handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/lz7m8hr2s...', 74, Array) #2 [internal function]: Drupal\simple_access\Element\SimpleAccessGroups::processSimpleAccessGroups(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Array) #3 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(997): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(1060): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm('node_page_edit*...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #5 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(1060): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm('node_page_edit*...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #6 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(561): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm('node_page_edit_...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #7 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(318): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('node_page_edit_...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #8 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(93): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('node_page_edit_...', Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #9 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch)) #10 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #11 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(582): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() #12 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure)) #13 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) #14 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() #15 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #16 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #17 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #18 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #19 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #20 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #21 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #22 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #23 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(693): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #24 /home/lz7m8hr2s8ob/public_html/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #25 {main}.

Comment: Any errors in the Drupal log? `/admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: That's not a standard Node edit widget. You're using some kind of module there, either contrib or custom. We can't guess what it is obviously, so please edit your question and add some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this. The solution was to unpublish the page and make a new one. Someone at my organisation told me they did that, but I just tried it myself, and it seems fine.